# redirect user to a new window in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a authentication device that on successful transaction returns only `ok`. If the output is anything else but `ok`, it won't work and throw error.

On successful transaction it's redirected to page `cams-attendance.php` which returns the value `ok`.

```
<?php
echo 'ok';
?>
```

I want to redirect the user to a another page in a new window.
I tried header, but header cannot redirect to a new window. I've tried javascript. But as it's more than `ok`, I'm getting error.

```
<?php
echo 'ok';
?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">window.open('http://www.example.com');</script>
```

using this code, the output is -

```
ok
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">window.open('http://www.example.com');</script>
```

So, as it's printing more than ok, the device is throwing error.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: How should it work? Do you want a timeout so that you can read "ok" and then redirect to new URL? Did you try http code 302/303 redirect?

Comment: @Tanmay added my solution below.

Comment: What do you mean by _"But as it's more than ok, I'm getting error."_. Also, what error are you getting? I'm guessing there are more code here? Do you have some conditions (`if`-statements) as well? Please show us _all_ the relevant code.

Comment: @Magnus, I don't have any if condition. I've edited the question with more clarification.

Comment: _"the device is throwing error"_ - What device? What's the error? You need to give us _all_ the information. Where is this code called from? Who is calling it?

Comment: this is a fingerprint sensor device. Upon successful recognition, it calls the above php code to print ok. Only 'ok' nothing else. I need to redirect to another page with  variable $user that I get from the device. As in the new page, I need some user input as well, so I need it to be in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your final variable is $resp and I have assigned the value "ok" to it. Here I check to see whether the $resp is equal to "ok" and if there is a match I echo out the javascript which pops up the new website on page load.

```
<?php $resp = "ok";
 if($resp=="ok"){
?>
<script>
   window.onload = function() {
      window.open('http://www.example.com');
   };
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the response you where looking for maybe but

I strongly suggest you to keep the logic server-side. The reason is simple: the context is security and as a general thumbs you should never ever trust the client to do what is right when what is right is not changing a variable the client control. What if the client change the variable? Would it mean it has the right now because he/she flip a variable? What you trying to achieve should be done the server-side way imo.

Comment: I don't agree with your thought on this... The variable is actually set on the server side. How will the client change the variable?

Comment: In this case the variable is the location. Put it that way; if one is told to accept any request simply because it was redirect on 'OK' then a malicious user could just request the location even if he didn't receive the 'OK'.